# How to aggregate reports given by nestat?

Tags: netstat

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/842585/getting-system-lacked-sufficient-buffer-space-or-because-a-queue-was-full) OP gives some reports that has been generated with `netstat`. However, the more I look at the switches of `netstat`, the less I can find how to generate that report.

The sample report is:

```
Process Id = 0, State = TIME_WAIT have 130,053 ports open
Process Id = 38840, State = CLOSE_WAIT have 5 ports open
Process Id = Any, State = LISTENING have 30 ports open
Process Id = Any, State = ESTABLISHED have 10 ports open
```

I need it to troubleshoot a problem of my server's network. How should I generate aggregated reports using `netstat`?